# Calculate probability of an event happening given past data

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am sure that this is a simple problem for many but I am having trouble finding a solution for this:

I have the sales history of a certain specific product-A being sold from a supermarket store. Specifically, I have the data on:

1) the maximum number of units of product-A on the shelves everyday (at the start of the day)

2) the minimum number of units of product-A remaining on the shelves on that day (after certain units are sold/damaged/broken at the end of the day)

I have the above data for over a period of 90 days.

Given this data and the fact that the sales of product-A aren't affected significantly in any holiday season, what is the number of units of product-A I should hold on the shelves at the beginning of the day, with a 90% certainty that it doesn't drop to zero at the end of the day?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: There isn't much to go on here...a priori the "loss number" (sales +waste) might not be terribly predictive from day to day.  The pattern of sales of Halloween materials in October doesn't tell us what sales will be like on November 1.  If you believe that there is a pattern, you need to model it somehow.  For example, you might imagine that the loss number is normally distributed about its mean.  Does the data support that or not?  Without any data and without any sort of guiding model, there really isn't much to say.

Comment: From your comment I realised that the question wasn't clearly framed enough. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: The question pertains to one specific product, called "product-A" for example, instead of all products in the store.

Comment: Well, as I say, you need some sort of model.  Simplest one is the one I mentioned..."the loss number is normally distributed".  Under that assumption, you can compute the mean and work out what number gives you a $90\%$ margin of safety.  I suggest plotting the data...if you think it's normal then aggregating the loss numbers by buckets should give you a picture like the standard normal.  Does it?  There are more sophisticated confidence tests, but the simple plot should help.  Of course you can just use the actual distribution given by the data!  Inelegant, but simple.

Comment: Do you mean that from the data, I should calculate the mean, std dev and then a confidence interval for 90%, and for whatever value I select from this confidence interval, will be my required number of units to hold?                       I am a newbie in stats, so please bear with me.

Comment: Well, if you are using the literal data then it is even simpler than that.  Just take the threshold $T$ such that $90\%$ of the observations are below $T$.  That's certainly the simplest thing to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I really appreciate it :)